# Add Multiple WebGrids with Styles in One Page without Redundancy

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, webgrid

Basically, here's my code inside the view and I don't want to repeat WebGrid instances.

**My Model**

```
public class UsersWithDetailsModels
{
    public IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<PersonalInfo> PersonalInfos { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CreditHistory> CreditHistories { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}
```

**My Controller**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Index(UsersWithDetailsModels model)
{
    return View(model);  // HERE: I can't get any data from database
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<Lml.Models.UsersWithDetailsModels>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
    Layout = null;

    // TABLE 1 with pager
    var pg = new WebGrid(Model, defaultSort: "Id", canPage: true, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "borrowersAppliedTable");
    pg.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);

    // TABLE 2 with pager
    var hg = new WebGrid(Model, defaultSort: "Id", canPage: true, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "borrowersAppliedAddressTable");
    hg.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);

    // TABLE 3 with pager
    var hg = new WebGrid(Model, defaultSort: "Id", canPage: true, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "borrowersAppliedMailingTable");
    hg.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);
}
```

You can obviously see how redundant it is.

Also, I have here the **column styles**

```
<!-- TABLE 1 -->
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <h2>Borrowers Applied</h2>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        @pg.GetHtml(
            htmlAttributes: new { id = "borrowersAppliedTable" },
            tableStyle: "table table-bordered table-hover table-striped",
            footerStyle: "table-footer text-center",
            columns:
                pg.Columns(
                    pg.Column(columnName: "Id", header: "Entry ID", format: (item) => item.GetSelectLink(item.Id.ToString())),
                    pg.Column(columnName: "DateApplied", header: "Entry Date"),
                    pg.Column(columnName: "FullName", header: "Full Name"),
                    pg.Column(columnName: "Email", header: "Email address")
            )
        )
    </div>
</div>

<!-- TABLE 2 -->
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <h2>Home Addresses</h2>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        @hg.GetHtml(
            htmlAttributes: new { id = "borrowersAppliedAddressTable" },
            tableStyle: "table table-bordered table-hover table-striped",
            footerStyle: "table-footer text-center",
            columns:
                hg.Columns(
                    hg.Column(columnName: "Id", header: "Entry ID", format: (item) => item.GetSelectLink(item.Id.ToString())),
                    hg.Column(columnName: "Street", header: "Street Address"),
                    hg.Column(columnName: "City", header: "City/Municipality"),
                    hg.Column(columnName: "Zip", header: "ZIP Code"),
                    hg.Column(columnName: "State", header: "Province/State"),
                    hg.Column(columnName: "Country")
        )) 
    </div>
</div>

<!-- TABLE 3 -->
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <h2>Mailing Addresses</h2>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        @hg.GetHtml(
            htmlAttributes: new { id = "borrowersAppliedMailingTable" },
            tableStyle: "table table-bordered table-hover table-striped",
            footerStyle: "table-footer text-center",
            columns:
                hg.Columns(
                    hg.Column(columnName: "Id", header: "Entry ID", format: (item) => item.GetSelectLink(item.Id.ToString())),
                    hg.Column(columnName: "MailStreet", header: "Street Address"),
                    hg.Column(columnName: "MailCity", header: "City/Municipality"),
                    hg.Column(columnName: "MailZip", header: "ZIP Code"),
                    hg.Column(columnName: "MailState", header: "Province/State"),
                    hg.Column(columnName: "MailCountry", header: "Country")
            )
        )
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see these lines, I want to apply that on every table.

```
tableStyle: "table table-bordered table-hover table-striped",
footerStyle: "table-footer text-center",
```

I don't want to repeat that again and again.

Could anyone help me know the shortcut or is there any short and tidy method in displaying multiple WebGrids in one page?

Comment: You have many ways to write code once, like partial views, child actions, helpers... Or do you want to actually have single instance of WebView and reuse it for rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to create configuration object for grids and loop through them to generate actual html:

```
@model Lml.Models.UsersWithDetailsModels

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
    Layout = null;

    var configs = new[]
    {
        new
        {
            Model = (IEnumerable<object>)Model.ApplicationUsers,
            Id = "borrowersAppliedTable",
            Header = "Borrowers Applied",
            Columns = new[]
            {
                new {Name = "UserId", Header = "Entry ID"},
                new {Name = "DateApplied", Header = "Entry Date"},
                new {Name = "FullName", Header = "Full Name"},
                new {Name = "Email", Header = "Email address"}
            }
        },
        new
        {
            Model = (IEnumerable<object>)Model.PersonalInfos,
            Id = "borrowersAppliedAddressTable",
            Header = "Home Addresses",
            Columns = new[]
            {
                new {Name = "Id", Header = "Entry ID"},
                new {Name = "Street", Header = "Street Address"},
                new {Name = "City", Header = "City/Municipality"},
                new {Name = "Zip", Header = "ZIP Code"},
                new {Name = "State", Header = "Province/State"},
                new {Name = "Country", Header = "Country"}
            }
        },
        new
        {
            Model = (IEnumerable<object>)Model.CreditHistories,
            Id = "borrowersAppliedMailingTable",
            Header = "Mailing Addresses",
            Columns = new[]
            {
                new {Name = "Id", Header = "Entry ID"},
                new {Name = "MailStreet", Header = "Street Address"},
                new {Name = "MailCity", Header = "City/Municipality"},
                new {Name = "MailZip", Header = "ZIP Code"},
                new {Name = "MailState", Header = "Province/State"},
                new {Name = "MailCountry", Header = "Country"}
            }
        },
        ...
    };
    var tables = configs.Select(config =>
    {
        var grid = new WebGrid(config.Model, defaultSort: config.Columns[0].Name, canPage: true, ajaxUpdateContainerId: config.Id);
        grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);

        return new { Id = config.Id, Grid = grid, Header = config.Header, Columns = config.Columns};
    });
}

@{
    foreach (var table in tables)
    {
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <h2>@table.Header</h2>
            <div class="table-responsive">
                @table.Grid.GetHtml(
                    htmlAttributes: new {id = table.Id },
                    tableStyle: "table table-bordered table-hover table-striped",
                    footerStyle: "table-footer text-center",
                    columns:
                        table.Grid.Columns(
                            table.Columns.Select((column, i) =>
                            {
                                return i == 0
                                    ? table.Grid.Column(columnName: column.Name, header: column.Header, format: (item) => item.GetSelectLink(item.Id.ToString()))
                                    : table.Grid.Column(columnName: column.Name, header: column.Header);
                            }).ToArray())
                    )
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: @Xtravagant, was my answer helpful or were you looking for different approach?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what if the first table has only the column name **Id** and the rest is named **UserID**? I already did this and received an error `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Lml.Models.UsersWithDetailsModels', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Lml.Models.UsersWithDetailsModels]'.` because I have multiple models in one view.

Comment: Didn't worked for me, got an error `No best type found for implicitly-typed array`. How can I fix that?

Comment: @Xtravagant, try cast each collection to `object`. It will fix the problem with anonymous type. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is no out of the box solution for default style for all of your WebGrids. However, to make it future proof you can apply the same style class for all of your WebGrids and then on document load loop through all of them and apply the style you want. This way whenever you change your style names, you will only have to change it in one place:

```
        @hg.GetHtml(
        htmlAttributes: new { id = "borrowersAppliedAddressTable" },
        tableStyle: "webgrid",
        headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
        footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
        columns:
            hg.Columns(
                hg.Column(columnName: "Id", header: "Entry ID", format: (item) => item.GetSelectLink(item.Id.ToString())),
                hg.Column(columnName: "Street", header: "Street Address"),
                hg.Column(columnName: "City", header: "City/Municipality"),
                hg.Column(columnName: "Zip", header: "ZIP Code"),
                hg.Column(columnName: "State", header: "Province/State"),
                hg.Column(columnName: "Country")
    ))
```

JQuery:

```
function ApplyStyles() {
    $('.webgrid').addClass('table table-bordered table-hover table-striped');
    $('.webgrid-header').addClass('table-header text-center');
    $('.webgrid-footer').addClass('table-footer text-center');
}
```

I understand this will not reduce the amount of code you have to write, but at least it will make it more manageable.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, I've been also asking how to display multiple webgrids and not only their class names.